# Non-linearly additive spectral subtraction?

Tags: algorithms

The following pictures describe my situation. Any thoughts on an appropriate algorithm I could use to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: any reason you cannot attenuate those peaks by multiplying the spectrum of the peaks you don't like by zero or some very small number?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to suggest an algorithm without knowing more about the nature of these signals, but if it really is as simple as the above situation, then a spectral subtraction approach which uses the reference 'Single Substance' signal to activate a binary mask might do the job for you.